# Display a particular view controller at launch based on a setting in user defaults

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I want to ask the user a question, once, at launch, in my iOS app. I have the view controller built to display the text and a button to answer.

I also have this in my app delegate file to detect if it has been answered before or not:

```
if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"questionAnswered"])
```

I know how to add a method to the button that changes the `questionAnswered` value.

What do I put in the above if statement to make that view controller appear?

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to check for this in your initial view controller and present the Terms and Conditions view.  The following will init and present the view from your view controller:

```
UIViewController *tncView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsViewController"];
[tncView setModalInPopover:YES];
[tncView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[tncView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];

[self presentViewController:tncView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Then, from your T&C view controller, to exit:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
```

UPDATE: If you are using a .xib file for your view, then just initialize it as so:

```
termsViewController *tncView = [[termsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"termsView" bundle:nil];
```

Where `termsViewController` is the class name for your EULA's view controller, and `termsView` is the name of your xib/nib file, without the extension (iOS 4.0+ doesn't require the extension).

If you didn't use a nib/xib and wrote the view controller programmatically:

```
termsViewController *tncView = [[termsViewController alloc] init];
```

If using a storyboard, you'd use what I posted above:

```
    UIViewController *tncView = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TermsViewController"];
```

After initializing the view controller, you set its presentation properties:

```
[tncView setModalInPopover:YES];
[tncView setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFormSheet];
[tncView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal];
```

And, finally, present the view.  I would do it in your initial view controller's `viewDidAppear` method:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self presentViewController:tncView animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Let me know if this works out for you.

Comment: My initial view controller? It is a tabbed bar application if that helps. I am not using story board either, just have the .xib, .m and .h files.

Comment: It shouldn't be much different. I'll update my answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Apple states in the HIG:

> If you provide an end-user license agreement (or EULA) with your iOS
>   app, the App Store displays it so that people can read it before they
>   get your app.
>
> If possible, avoid requiring users to indicate their agreement to your
>   EULA when they first start your app. Without an agreement displayed,
>   users can enjoy your app without delay. However, even though this is
>   the preferred user experience, it might not be feasible in all cases.
>   If you must display a license agreement within your app, do so in a
>   way that harmonizes with your user interface and causes the least
>   inconvenience to users.
>
> If possible, provide a disclaimer within your app description or EULA.
>   Users can then view the disclaimer in the App Store, and you can
>   balance business requirements with user experience needs.

Apple provides a place to put a custom EULA in iTunes Connect.

Comment: I have certainly seen ToC in-app before, particularly when there is an update.

Comment: This is being mandated by my company's legal department. Apple's guidelines says they will reject if the decline button exits the app; they recommend a screen saying to press the home button or accept, OR not putting a decline button at all and forcing them to accept to use the app.

Comment: I would have a basically empty view that just says something along the lines of "Sorry, but to use this app you must accept our Terms and Conditions.  Press (here) to view our EULA, or press the Home button to exit the app."

Comment: This isn't the issue. I am being forced to implement it, not discuss whether Apple will reject it or not. Can you help with the original question?

Comment: Richard Brown makes a good point, that it isn't always optimal to do it the way that you need to do, but for peace of mind know that the App Store Review Guidelines don't say anything about it. (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html - Note: developer login required).

Comment: This has nothing to do with the _technical_ question at hand, which is how to display a particular view controller. This answer is essentially off-topic. Pretend it's just a login page.